# how to make which(x) run when all FALSE in x?

Tags: r

```
> x<-c(FALSE,FALSE)
> which(x)
integer(0)
> which(x)==0
logical(0)
> x<-c(FALSE,TRUE)
> which(x)
[1] 2
```

In my program,i don't know what x is,x is a logical vector,maybe contain TRUE,if it contain TRUE,print the order,if it don't contain TRUE at all,print 0.

Integer(0) is not the same as 0?what is the difference?what is the meaning of logical(0)?
`which(x)` can not do,when no TRUE in x ,`which(x)` can do,when there is TRUE in x.
how can i fulfil my target?

Comment: `integer(0)` is an integer vector with no entries at all, and similarly for `logical(0)`. If you want to check whether the vector is empty you can use `which(x) == integer(0)` or `length(which(x)) == 0`.

Comment: You can use `match(TRUE, x, nomatch=0)`

Comment: Hi, logical(o) mean than the result is a vector of logical value of length(0) (an absence of value). Integer(0) means that the results is a vector of integer without value. With which you are aksing for an index value, if there is no TRUE in your logical vector then you can't return an index for the TRUE value.

Comment: why not 0? I can assign this kind of meaning with 0.

Comment: Why not `0`? Look at it this way: `length(which(x))` should be equal to the number of places where `x` is `TRUE`. If `x` contains zero `TRUE`, then it makes sense that `length(which(x))` should be `0`. `length(0)` is `1` while `length(integer(0))` is `0`. The latter is what makes most sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if any value in the vector x is true with

```
any(x)
```

rather than which() so

```
if (any(x)) {
    #print order
} else {
    print(0)
}
```

Comment: Indeed!  `which(Logic)` is used  **way** too often, in many places where one could and should use `Logic` itself, exactly the way @MrFlick shows above.